# Spatial analysis with weights

Tags: spatial

I am estimating some spatial models. I would like to know if it is possible to include sample weights. In other words does it existna spatial counterpart to weighted least square? I tried to google this but apparently I was not able to find anything.

Thanks for any suggestion

EDIT

Basically, l estimate the following model:

y = a + bX + dWy + u

where u = kWu + e

W is a weights matrix based on the inverse distance between regions, while a, b, d and k are parameters to be estimated. So i am assuming that there exists spatial dependence on the residuals, as well as spillover effects through the spatially lagged dependent variable.

Using the model above i would like to estimate within a spatial framework the following equation:

y = a + bX + u

which is taken from a paper I am following in my analysis. The author of that paper suggests to estimate the latter equation using a WLS, adding sample weights in the estimation.

My question:

Is there anyway I can add sample weights to the estimation of the spatial model (obviously in addition to the spatial weights?).

My search so far was unsuccessful.

I hope to have clarified my question adequately.

Comment: What kind of model?  What estimation procedure?

Comment: I am using a sarar